# Why is Software Updater making me install all these FIrefox language packs, even if I don't have Firefox installed?

Tags: updates, language, firefox

I'm using a clean install of Freya (made about a month ago), and suddenly Software Updater started including all these language packs. [image]

I had the same issue with a previous install of Freya; it just looks like, after a while, elementary just decides to start installing all these language packs.

By the way, the only language I have installed is english (the default one) and I'm using an Italian keyboard, as you can see above.

EDIT - after using `sudo apt-get remove firefox-locale-*` it *seems* for now that elementary has stopped trying to install those packages. Of course, this removes *every* language pack in Firefox, which I however didn't have to begin with.

Comment: I too have noted all the firefox language packs on a new Eos install. For the funny part, Firefox is not (yet) installed. I suspect a few cleanable strings in the installer configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The poster found a solution:

`sudo apt remove firefox-locale-*`